# Relative URL in enterprise application

Tags: jsf-2

How can I output a relative URL with JSF? Whenever I add a relative link JSF adds the context root itself, which seems kind of odd to me. Usually in HTML a relative link is relative to the domain? So how do I output a relative link to another context root in my application?

So if I am in context root A, I want to write a link to /B/myPage.xhtml

I use Myfaces 2.1.9

Comment: using a simple <a href="/B/myPage.xhtml">page</a> is not working?

Comment: yes, that works, but I use several components (like outputLink, primefaces megamenu etc) that takes a URL and does this conversion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by implementing a custom ViewHandler where I override getResourceURL. There I check if the URL already have an context path and if so I don't call the original super method (which adds the context path)

Comment: Could you provide some code, if you still have it lying somewhere ... optimistic

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but I don't have access to this code anymore

Answer (score 1):

from [primefaces menu showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu.jsf)

```
<p:menu>  
    ...

    <p:submenu label="Navigations">  
        <p:menuitem value="External" url="http://www.primefaces.org" icon="ui-icon-home"/>  
        <p:menuitem value="Internal" outcome="/mobile/index" icon="ui-icon-star"/>  
    </p:submenu>  
</p:menu>
```

so you can use a semi-external like

```
<p:menuitem value="External" url="#{request.scheme}://#{request.serverName}:#{request.serverPort}/B/page.html" icon="ui-icon-home"/>
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but this won't work because load balancers and other infrastructure seem to make the request.servername to not be the correct one. I guess I can hard code it.